# Issue with Bitmap Quality after Scaling/Decoding in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, scaling, android-bitmap

I have the following getBitmap() and decode() code. The url image asset is 1080x1920 jpeg image. My phone is also 1080x1920 in dimension. However, after performing the following functions and getting the Bitmap, I am doing the following:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
relativeLayout.setBackground(imageView.getDrawable());
```

Is there an issue with the decoding/scaling in the code below?

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null){
            Log.d(TAG, "getBitmap() - Decoded from File successfully");
            return b;   
        }

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: It is ok. If the loss renders the image unrecognizable or with far too big one color areas, you can do a two step scale or so. I mean scale to a mid aize and then that to the definitive

Comment: Thanks for your response @eduyayo . Could you please let me know which lines I'd need to update to improve the image quality?

Comment: For some reason, I have an image asset from a url and it is 700KB. I monitored the memory usage, and every time I added a new imageview, it would increase significant (5mb or so) per image. My app will be displaying many images at a given time, and I'm trying to minimize the memory consumption while using a decent image quality.

Comment: Use picasso as @slogamo suggests. It will handle the recycling and scaling for you so the memory consuption is lower. What i meant before with the two step is that if the image is 1000 px width and you've gotta render it as a 50px icon, it is better to scale it down in two or even three steps: 1000px->300px->50px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awesome third party library that I use in my app. Images resize beautifully. Hope it can help. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Thank you @Sloganho for the recommendation. For some reason... when I tried using picasso, lets say I had an image asset from a url and it was 700KB. I monitored the memory usage, and every time I added a new imageview, it would increase significant (5mb or so) per image. My app will be displaying many images at a given time, and I'm trying to minimize the memory consumption while using a decent image quality. Does picasso allow to configure the memory consumption or image quality?

Comment: This one seems to be more customizable and better for bigger pictures. I don't know a ton about picasso so I'm sorry. But maybe you could check this one out. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader.   http://www.opensourcealternative.org/tutorials/android-tutorials/android-picasso-vs-universal-image-loader/